# Do the things I do before I buy Eye of the North count for HoM?

Tags: guild-wars

Basically. If I don't have Eye of the North, can the things I do before I find the Hall of Monuments be added, or would I need to start a new character after buying Eye of the North?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all of your prior achievements will count, but you'll need to interact with the monuments in the Hall of Monuments after you buy EotN for them to count.

Another good thing to know is that your cumulative achievements on all of your characters will count towards Guild Wars 2, and can be tracked at [hom.guildwars2.com](http://hom.guildwars2.com).

Comment: Thank you! I figured it would work that way because it would be terrible for the old players, but clarification never hurts.

Comment: Yeah, Arenanet is usually good about not burning their existing players when they add new things, but it doesn't hurt to ask. If you want to accept my answer as the correct one, please click on the grey check mark to the left of the answer. Not trying to be pushy, just noticing that you're a new user, and a lot of new users miss that. :)

Comment: After I saw the answer I tried, it told me I had to wait 11 minutes, so I came back to do just that. Thank you again for the quick answer, I can hold off on Eye of the North for another week.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the 15 minute timer, sorry. No problem on the quick answer, I happened to check the questions list less than a minute after you asked. By the way, I added a little more info to my answer just now. Good luck with your achievements!

Comment: It should be noted that when linking your account from GW1 to your GW2 account, if for some reason you have more than one GW1 account like I did, make sure you link the correct accountss or you pretty much lose out on all of your achievements. I still haven't gotten mine fixed yet :(